# Regular Expression engine that supports raw UTF-8?

Tags: c++, regex

I need a regular expression engine that supports raw UTF-8 - meaning, the UTF-8 string is stored in char * as two chars(or one, or less) - for example, Ab is the array {0x41,0x62}.
Anyone know of an regex engine that can receive that format?
I can convert to wchar_t if needed first.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/unicode.html) says that it is possible with Boost.Regex, on the condition that you configure and use [ICU library](http://www.ibm.com/software/globalization/icu/).

Answer (score 0):

> The  current  implementation of PCRE
>   (release 7.x) corresponds approxi-
>          mately with Perl 5.10, including support for UTF-8 encoded
>   strings  and
>          Unicode general category properties. However, UTF-8 and Unicode
>   support
>          has to be explicitly enabled; it is not the default. The Unicode
>   tables
>          correspond to Unicode release 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with the non constant character length nature of UTF-8 makes it very hard to create algorithms (like regex).

It's better to convert the utf-8 string to a unicode wstring with [ICU](http://www.ibm.com/software/globalization/icu/) and then use the wstring variant of [boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5F38%5F0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost%5Fregex/unicode.html)